# Better instructions how to use a micrometer

Tags: tools

I am confused by [these instructions](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-and-Read-an-Outside-Micrometer) on how to use a micrometer.  Does anyone know of better ones?  I need to measure the thickness of my valve lifters (and then do a feeler gauge test but that is not done with a micrometer) because I didn't keep track of my valve lifter before taking apart.

Comment: Watch the video which is near the bottom. It is a lot better in explaining it and gives several examples. Remember the vernier scale is on the backside of the main scale. Also, the first part of the instructions where it says "2.xxx" ... the two is actual inches which you will know because of what size of micrometer you are using. [The video at the end](https://youtu.be/i_jygJkJujE) explains it about 2000x better than the written instructions. Also, I think the written instructions are actually wrong (at least in the examples).

Comment: @Paulster2 : I can see at least two mistakes in the diagrams. Confusing for sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Those instructions sure are confusing!

I can see a couple of places where the wiki instructions are clear as mud.

1. The example states that the micrometer in the example is meant to measure lengths between 2" and 3":

   > In this particular example, the micrometer measures the range from 2" to 3”

   And then 2.1 highlights the 2 on the sleeve for no logical reason whatsoever. This has nothing to do with how the 2 in 2.545 is obtained. ***I wouldn't pay any attention to Step 2.1***:

   [image: Confusion #1]
2. The small markings on the sleeve look like they should be 50-thousandths while the explanation treats it as a 25-thousandths marking in 2.3.

   [image]

---

The example isn't coherent with the images. I'd recommend watching [the video](https://youtu.be/i_jygJkJujE) as @Paulster2 suggests in the comments.